# Can't set validationErrors from beforeFilter

Tags: cakephp

I can't set the valitationErrors from beforeFilter. Why?

```
function beforeFilter () {
    if ($this->Session->check('errors')) {
        $this->validationErrors = array ('Question' => array('text' => 'notEmpty'));
    }
}
```

I tried both "$this->validationErrors" and "$this->Model->validationErrors" and none of them seem to work. When I go to the view, Debug Kit reports that the $this->validationErrors variable is empty.

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you're trying to get them in the beforeFilter() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just figured it out that when you change validationErrors, the model you use to call it, is the model it will validate. So if you want to validate Questions, you should call $this->Question->validationErrors = ...

Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, but maybe the model hasn't been init at that stage. You may need to save that for use in the actual action.

Comment: That was a good idea. But I can't set it on the controller either. :(

Comment: what do you mean? isn't beforeFilter a controller method? You can try to log the output of $this->ModelName to see if it's null. You can save the errors to the Session and use it later, because they are not rendered until the view anyway.